# Why am I receiving this 500 (Internal Server Error) on my Heroku deployed React.js/Node.js/Express.js app even though everything works?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, model-view-controller

I have a deployed application and I am experiencing an issue with my contact form. This is a React.js app with a node, express and mongoDB backend. It is deployed on Heroku.

Right now, when a user enters their information into the contact form it:
1. runs `API.saveLead()` which runs a `fetch()` hits the `contact/lead` route. The data is saved to the database. 
2. then `API.sendMail()` is called which runs a `fetch()` to the `contact/mail` route. The data is packaged and appropriately sent to the desired email address using the nodemailer package.

Although everything is functioning appropriately, I am logging a 500 (Internal Server Error) and I cannot figure out why. This is the error:

```
API.js:29 POST https://www.agavepv.com/contact/mail 500 (Internal Server Error)
sendMail @ API.js:29
(anonymous) @ index.js:38
Promise.then (async)
t.handleFormSubmit @ index.js:36
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:80
w @ react-dom.production.min.js:100
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:104
T @ react-dom.production.min.js:124
P @ react-dom.production.min.js:153
C @ react-dom.production.min.js:142
N @ react-dom.production.min.js:166
xn @ react-dom.production.min.js:1676
ue @ react-dom.production.min.js:7257
_n @ react-dom.production.min.js:1741
Nn @ react-dom.production.min.js:1778
Pn @ react-dom.production.min.js:1753
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:270
Ql @ react-dom.production.min.js:2794
ie @ react-dom.production.min.js:7242
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:1710
```

The link to my gitHub can be found here: https://github.com/TheGreekCuban/agavepv
The link to the deployed site can be found here: https://www.agavepv.com

UPDATE

```
module.exports = {
  create: function(req, res) {
    db.Lead
      .create(req.body)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
//THE CODE BELOW IS WHERE I THE ERROR IS BEING TRIGGERED
  send: function(req) {
    db.Send(req.body)
    .then(response => console.log("Message[2]: ", response))
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response));
  }
};
```

UPDATE [2]

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")


const Send = (request) => {

    console.log("Request2: ", request)

    const output = `
        <p>Name: ${request.Name}</p>
        <p>Phone: ${request.Phone}</p>    
        <p>Email: ${request.Email}</p>
        <p>Message:
        <br>
        ${request.Message}</p>        
    `

    // call the main function which will take care of the nodemailer.
    main(output)
}

async function main(output) {
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: process.env.email, // generated ethereal user
            pass: process.env.password // generated ethereal password
        }
    });

    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: '"Admin" <[TAKENOUTFOREXAMPLE]@[EXAMPLE].com>', // sender address
        to: "[TAKENOUTFOREXAMPLE]@[EXAMPLE].com", // list of receivers
        subject: "Interested in working with you!", // Subject line
        html: output // html body
    });

    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou... 
    return console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
}
// Export the model
module.exports = Send;
```

Comment: can you access the logs to see what the error is?

Comment: 2020-03-10T19:38:52.422915+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
2020-03-10T19:38:52.422916+00:00 app[web.1]: at send (/app/controllers/leadController.js:13:5) @azium

Comment: Okay.. can you post the `leadController` code where it can't read `then` of undefined.. clearly that's what's wrong

Comment: Ok, I just updated the post and commented which block of code is causing the error on the leadController file. @azium

Comment: what is `db`? is that something you wrote? did you write the `Send` method? does it return a promise?

Comment: db is a model. Yes I wrote it and yes it should be returning a promise. I posted that code under update [2]. @azium

Comment: it clearly doesn't return a promise, you don't even have a `return` statement anywhere

Comment: did you mean to put `return main(output)` at the end of `Send`?

Comment: but even still your `main` function doesn't return anything.. you can't return a console log statement, but that's not going to throw the 500, that'll just give you an undefined response inside `then`.

Comment: what do you return if you don't need to  send anything back @azium

Comment: you don't have to return anything.. but if you don't return anything then you obviously can't call `then`, which is exactly what your error says, can't read `then` of undefined

Comment: I removed the .then and .catch from the send method in leadController. Now I receive a 503 request timeout. @azium

Comment: that's because you're not calling `res.end` or `res.json`. basically your endpoint is timing out because you're not sending a response back

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! @azium